# Compute Confidence Interval for Binomial Distribution

Tags: distributions

I want to understand how to calculate hypothesis tests on a Binomial distribution. An example is something like

A diagnostic test is claimed to be correct 96% of the time. On a sample of 75, 68 results were correct. Does this result support a confidence level of 90% that the claim is true?

I can see that I can do this:

```
x=60
CDF[BinomialDistribution[75, 0.96], x]
```

and by trial-and-error find the values of x that result in CDF values of 5%, 95%. How do I get the correct value of x without the trial and error?

Comment: Look at `Quantile`, e.g. `Quantile[BinomialDistribution[75, .96], {0.05, 0.95}]` for a direct Q&D, may suffice for your actual coverage needs.

Comment: Yes indeed, that counts as an answer for me. Thankyou